# What is the keyboard shortcut to switch between open applications inside Citrix?

Tags: citrix-access-gateway

I am using Citrix Access Gateway to connect to a Remote Desktop and I am not able to find a way to switch between open applications.  When I press 'Alt + Tab' it comes out of the remote desktop.  I mean, the whole remote desktop is getting considered as 1 open application.
Is there any other keyboard shortcut to switch between open applications inside Citrix?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Close Citrix Remote Desktop, if it is already running.
2. In our local machine, go to ‘Regedit’ and open ‘TransparentKeyPassthrough’.  Set the value to ‘Remote’ and close.[*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE* → *SOFTWARE* → *Citrix* → *ICA Client* → *Engine* → *Lockdown Profiles* → *All Regions* → *Lockdown* → *Virtual Channels* → *Keyboard*]
3. Login to the usual Citrix page. Before clicking on the ‘Remote Desktop’, check the ‘Preferences → Session Settings’.  Choose ‘Fullscreen’ from dropdown.
4. Click ‘Remote Desktop’ now.
5. Login to the Remote Desktop
6. You should see  a blue bar at the top.
7. If you don’t see it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PAUSE</kbd>. Now you should see the blue bar.
8. Try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and you should be able to scroll through the open applications within remote desktop. Also, this enables you to save screenshots in the remote itself.
9. If you want to maximize the screen even more, Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.
10. To revert, you can press the same key combinations again.

Comment: For my Windows 7 Citrix client, the local REGEDIT path is just like @Ramnath explains, except under the **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** hive

Comment: On Windows 7, 64-bit, I have `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Citrix\ICA Client\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual Channels\Keyboard` (note the extra `Wow6432Node`).

Comment: And one for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and one for `HKEY_USERS`: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Citrix\ICA Client\Engine\Configuration\Advanced\Modules\TransparentKeyPassthrough` and `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2841079552-3630746606-3493918560-1717\Software\Citrix\ICA Client\Engine\Configuration\Advanced\Modules\TransparentKeyPassthrough`.

Comment: In the Age of COVID, this proved fantastically helpful. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: I was missing that Registry key at all (the part after Lockdown Profiles did not exist). It turned out that it was because I used Citrix from Windows Store. Installing it traditional way added way more registry keys.
Additionally if you want to do opposite of this setting, which is that you client/local PC would respond to alt+tab etc. then you can set the registry value to "Local"

Answer (score 2):

Got it working. Just to clarify:

In the Registry Editor -

For 32-bit OS, Citrix is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\

For 64-bit OS, Citrix is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\

However, I just changed it under HKEY_CURRENT_USER, and it worked.

Also, I chose "On the remote computer" from the "Keyboard" dropdown in the RDP Connection Local Resources tab.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article from Citrix support center on ["Enable toggle between applications using Alt-Tab keys within a remote desktop session"](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX232298)

> Launch Regedit.exe on the client device to edit the registry
>   For Windows 32-bit OS, navigate to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICAClient\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual Channels\Keyboard\
>
> For Windows 64-bit OS, navigate to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Citrix\ICA Client\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual Channels\Keyboard\
>
> In some cases configuring User based Setting also helps:  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICAClient\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Virtual Channels\Keyboard\

```
Set the below Value.
Value Name    TransparentKeyPassthrough 
Value Type    REG_SZ 
Value         Remote
```

**Note: You have to exit Receiver and launch it again for this change to take effect.**

Comment: I don't have admin privileges on my work PC so can only set this on the HKEY_CURRENT_USER, but by itself that doesn't work. Any idea how I could fix?

Comment: I'm using "Citrix Workspace" chrome app as a workaround for connection issues, does this have to be done in the same way in this case as well?