# Keyboard shortcut to toggle OUT of a Citrix Workspace Desktop Viewer session

Tags: accessibility, remote-desktop, citrix, citrix-access-gateway

**Background**

I'm using the Desktop Viewer functionality in Citrix Workspace (version 20.2.0.25(2002)) to access my work computer from my home computer.

**Request**

I would like to be able to toggle *out* of my (full-screen) remote session back to my local desktop more easily.

Currently I can only accomplish this via the control bar at the top of the remote session screen which is starting to feel tedious.
[image: Citrix session control bar]

`Alt+Tab` doesn't work, because it only toggles the applications within the remote session when the session is open.

Whether toggling is accomplished via getting `Alt+Tab` to work as desired, a hotkey that just minimizes the session window, or some other method doesn't matter to me.

**What I've Tried**

There are many [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528052/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-between-open-applications-inside-citrix) online addressing how to *enable* `Alt+Tab` within the remote session, but not *disable* it.  Naturally I've tried to do the reverse of these instructions but no luck.  They typically suggest setting `TransparentKeyPassthrough=Remote` in the registry of the local machine, so I figured mine should have `Remote` already and I would just need to clear it or replace it with something else, but mine is a null value.

I've gone through all options within Citrix Workspace and the Remote session Preferences but there's nothing about enabling/disabling/setting hotkeys.

I tried the "Disable Hotkeys through the ICACLIENT.ADM Template" of this [Citrix Support page](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX140219), but was unable to locate the icaclient template file they refer to.

I've contacted my company's help desk but they don't know of any solutions.

Comment: Hey any solution to this yet ?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Looks on-topic for Super User.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can access the citrix menu as described [here](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX232298):

> As an accessibility feature of the Desktop Viewer, pressing CTRL+ALT+BREAK
> displays the Desktop Viewer toolbar buttons in a pop-up window.

So the shortcut for toggling out of the viewer session would be:

```
CTRL + ALT + BREAK, CURSOR-DOWN, ENTER
```

Comment: I had to look around to know what `break` and `cursor down` were, event though it might be obvious to most users I put my local translation here in case it could helps people like me :
BREAK : Pause/Attn
CURSOR-DOWN : directional down arrow (⬇️)

Comment: laptop keyboards don't have break key. We have to use fn+B as a break key. Now, to use above shortcut we have to press CTRL + ALT + fn+ B, CURSOR-DOWN, ENTER. I think it is better to use mouse than this shortcut for laptop users.

Comment: I was stuck in a full-screen virtual desktop when the citrix menu crashed. You saved me from eternal virtuality, genius! :)

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect for me in combination with Elgato Stream Deck. There I can bind complicated shortcuts like this to a button!! Love it!

Comment: @MayankKumarThakur *"I think it is better to use mouse than this shortcut for laptop users"*. And what if a user has hand tremors and can't use a mouse? That's a huge accessibility issue. You should never suggest that a user use some device that works for you. They might be using a screen reader or magnifier or braille device or one of a myriad of other assistive technologies. A keyboard option **must** work.

Comment: This is a live safer for me.  I had a remote session that was full screen.  Due to a bug, my Citrix menu was missing (not displayed).

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and solved it with an Autohotkey script. Autohotkey can intercept keypresses even when citrix has focus.
This script will allow you to get out of your citrix session with Ctrl-F1.

```
^F1::
WinMinimize, A
return
```

If you have not used Autohotkey before: [Download Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), install it, save the code above in a file named `citrix.ahk`, double-click that file. The hotkey is now active and the script is visible as a `H` icon in your taskbar.
[See here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) if you want to bind a different key.

Comment: for whatever reason, for me to make this work, I needed to specify WinMinimize's WinTitle option to refer to the active window: `^F1::WinMinimize, A return`

Answer (score 7):

Unable to comment on ht13's answer so i'll post my own.

```
CTRL+ALT+BREAK, h
```

worked for me.

Thankfully i remembered some keyboards have BREAK, some (like mine) call it PAUSE in case you run into that too.

Answer (score 4):

I have a method for this that involves editing the registry on your local machine.
It definitely counts as 'some other method' - essentially, it sets up a keyboard shortcut that (I think) passes the Win-key keystroke to your local machine.
This opens your local start menu on top of Citrix - and from there you can `Alt+Tab` locally as normal.

Citrix has multiple entries in different parts of the registry, and also some settings that you can change with the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit). Unfortunately, the only one I've found that helps is 'Hotkey13', which is only available in the registry.

I've changed multiple things, but I believe the minimal necessary steps are this:

- open regedit, and navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICA Client\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Client Engine\Hot Keys\`
- ensure the value of AllowHotkey is set to `1`
- set the value of Hotkey13Shift; I've used `Shift`, if I recall correctly it accepts `Ctrl` and `Alt` and some combinations joined by `+`
- set the value of Hotkey13Char; I've used `F1`, and think it accepts all Fx keys and possibly some others
- restart Citrix, reconnect to your remote desktop, and test your chosen combination

Now, to access my local machine from within a Citrix session I press `Shift+F1` to open my local Start menu and give focus to my local machine, and then while it is open `Alt+Tab` or anything else acts locally.

[A screenshot of regedit highlighting Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ICA Client\Engine\Lockdown Profiles\All Regions\Lockdown\Client Engine\Hot Keys\Hotkey13Shift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjCHz.png)

Comment: Note: I had a working solution after a lot of research several months ago that I feel was different to this, but at one point I needed to reset my Citrix workspace which destroyed it. I found this question when I was trying to remember and re-create my previous solution and I have since used the approach outlined above, so apologies that the research and referenecs side of this is incomplete: I can't remember where I found some of these elements. I hope the answer is useful anyway.

Comment: With this solution, the Ctrl+'+' shortcut for adding new rows/columns didn't work anymore in the Citrix environment. Possibly other shortcuts were affected, too.

Answer (score 0):

this bothered me for so long and I finally got a fix: (AHK+Virtualdesktop)

1. put your citrix desktop viewer in a different virtual desktop
2. install AutoHotKey and Windows-desktop-switcher
   [https://github.com/vnavkal/windows-desktop-switcher#:~:text=An%20AutoHotkey%20script%20for%20Windows%20that%20lets%20a,desktops%20by%20hotkey%2C%20etc.%20%28see%20Hotkeys%20section%20below%29](https://github.com/vnavkal/windows-desktop-switcher#:%7E:text=An%20AutoHotkey%20script%20for%20Windows%20that%20lets%20a,desktops%20by%20hotkey%2C%20etc.%20%28see%20Hotkeys%20section%20below%29).

define whatever hotkey you want to use to toggle between different virtual desktop.
it seems the AHK is able to intercept the hotkey BEFORE it is send to the Desktop Viewer.

my setup:
I use a windows desktop and 2 extra display
I put citrix on virtual desktop2, and fullscreen to all 3 screens
use the hotkey to toggle back to laptop host window virtual desktop 1 without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

FN+F11 toggles out to my windows taskbar. Just need to click on the citrix icon on the task bar to go back again.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+Fn+B and then W for switching to window or F to get Citrix in full screen mode. A bit faster then using arrows ...

Answer (score 0):

Using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> you can resize the Citrix window and access the local machine taskbar so that you can easily switch between the apps.

Refer to this link: [CTX232298](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX232298/enable-alttab-hotkey-within-a-citrix-desktop-session-citrix-workspace-app#:%7E:text=If%20the%20Desktop%20Viewer%20is%20displayed%20in%20a%20window%2C%20ALT,full%2Dscreen%20and%20windowed%20mode).

Answer (score 0):

I place citrix workspace on separate windows desktop, and use CTRL + ALT + BREAK and then CTRL + WIN + LEFT/RIGHT to switch from it to another desktop.